# read.fwf with fixed position from SPSS code

Tags: r

I have a sample data like this

```
00013          326 10 5143 1 1 11 1 73311333111111111111511111111111111111511111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111            3                 3      875421212454542534524542133452421245443454234234544452124445454
00023          325 10 5143 1 1 11 1 74  1333111111111113111111111111111113111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111                                     864212322454542435434542143342412145443434324235454454542434543
```

and I need to read the individual data by fixed position from SPSS code, given the colume names and data position as shown in below (snippet code)

```
ID 1-4
QUARTER 5
SEX 7
AGEA 8
AGEB 9
RACE 10
OCCA 11
OCCB 12
LOCATION 13
REGION 14
EDUCATION 15
HHIA 16
HHIB 17
PERSONALINCOME 18
ENGLIT 19
CHILIT 20
RUMILIT 21
JAWILIT 22
TAMILLIT 23
MORELIT 24
ILLITERATE 25
MRO1 170
MRO2 171
MRO3 172
MRO4 173
MRO5 174
```

I have written the R code,

```
data <- read.fwf("MY/Q315-Q216.txt", widths=c(-4,4,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-144,1,1,1,1), header=FALSE, 
             col.names=c("ID",
                         "QUARTER",
                         "SEX",
                         "AGEA", 
                         "AGEB", 
                         "RACE" ,
                         "OCCA", 
                         "OCCB", 
                         "LOCATION",
                         "REGION", 
                         "EDUCATION",
                         "HHIA", 
                         "HHIB", 
                         "PERSONALINCOME", 
                         "ENGLIT", 
                         "CHILIT", 
                         "RUMILIT", 
                         "JAWILIT", 
                         "TAMILLIT", 
                         "MORELIT", 
                         "ILLITERATE", 
                         "MRO1",
                         "MRO2" ,
                         "MRO3" ,
                         "MRO4" ))
```

Is there an easier way to just use the position indicated in the SPSS code instead of specifying the widths one by one.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found it using read_fwf function

```
#read data
library(data.table)
library(readr)
mydata1 <- data.table(read_fwf("MY/Q315-Q216.txt", fwf_positions(
   c(5,9,21:39,176:180), 
   c(8,9,21:39,176:180), 
   c("ID",
     "QUARTER",
     "SEX", 
     "AGEA",
     "AGEB",
     "RACE",
     "OCCA",
     "OCCB",
     "LOCATION",
     "REGION",
     "EDUCATION",
     "HHIA",
     "HHIB",
     "PERSONALINCOME",
     "ENGLIT",
     "CHILIT",
     "RUMILIT",
     "JAWILIT",
     "TAMILLIT",
     "MORELIT",
     "ILLITERATE",
     "MRO1",
     "MRO2",
     "MRO3",
     "MRO4",
     "MRO5")))
```